# Noisey clunk in freehub, how to R&R the Hub

Tags: shimano, freehub, schwinn

[image]I have a Schwinn Pathway 18speed bike. I put about 60 miles a week on it, over the past 1.5 years. Recently I noticed a clunk in the rear wheel. All gears and only while pedaling. I cleaned it up and replaced the chain. same problem. put old chain back on, same. I noticed there is some bearing play in the freehub bearings side to side, like the bearings are loose or worn. The axle bearings are fine. I would like to remove the freehub and bearings to check, clean and relube. How do I remove the freehub? it appears to have an outer lock ring with notches on the outside. See pic.

Thank you in advance,

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on freewheels, but it look like this model freewheel has no splines or notches to insert a tool to remove the freewheel.   If this is the case, the easiest way it to dismantle the freewheel in place and it can then be removed, however this is destructive and requires a new freewheel.

Refer

[Parktool freewheel removal](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-removal-and-installation)

[Parktool  freewheel destructive removal](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/freewheel-destructive-removal)

Comment: If you zoom in, you can see it's a normal shimano freewheel splined tool that's needed.